# Set an User ID afterwards

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I was wondering, is it possible to set an User ID and track all the history of this user, even if it's not set since the first GA event ?

For example, if a visitor comes on my website, visits few pages... And then sets his email somewhere. I can send an event with a custom unique user ID, but is it possible to link this custom unique User ID with all the previous events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserId must be sent with all hits from that user. The moment you start sending it Analytics can fill in previous hits within the same session, that requires that you use Session Unification ON. All future hits on the same session must have userId, session unification will fill in previous hits but not future hits without userId.

It's not possible to do a unification with past sessions either.

I highly recommend that you read through the [Session Unification Help Center Article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660) where this behavior is well documented.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, thanks.
And about unification with past sessions, would you recommend any tool for that ?